# Megakit theme issue

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I downloaded bootstrap theme named Megakit from https://themewagon.com/themes/free-html5-css3-bootstrap-responsive-one-page-multipurpose-template/

It does not scroll with up down arrows or page up page down buttons. I have to do it manually by pressing scroll bar from mouse.

There is a scrollbar folder under vendor folder that has files

```
jquery.scrollbar.min.js 
scrollbar.min.css files
```

Under js/components we have

```
  scrollbar.js

  // Scrollbar
  var Scrollbar = function() {
  'use strict';

 // Handle Scrollbar
 var handleScrollbar = function() {
    $('.js__scrollbar').mCustomScrollbar({
      theme: 'minimal'
  });
}
```

How do I allow scrolling with arrow keys as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem comes from the smooth scroll javascript file 
short answer just remove

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
```

from your code